# The RPC server is unavailable (outlook in vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, interop

I am developing little application. It's purpose is on button click generate some email and open outlook "new email" window with this template. I am using Outlook interop 14. On application start I create New Outlook.Application() instance. This creates outlook.exe process.

My method for generating and open email:

```
Private Sub GenerateEmail(...)
         ...
         'this line throws RPC exception when no outlook.exe process exists
         Dim OutlookEmail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(OutlApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
         ...
         OutlookEmail.Display()
         ...
End Sub
```

When I run an application, outlook.exe process starts. I click generate email, outlook opens window BUT when I close this "new email" window it also terminates outlook.exe process. And this is problem becasue second time I want to generate an email I am getting an error "The RPC server is unavailable". The question is how to close the window but not terminate outlook process. Btw I am getting the same error also when I am try to second time create a new instance of Outlook.Application (after terminating a previous one).

Comment: Have you tried calling `Quit()` on your `Outlook.Application` object before opening a new instance?

Comment: Yes I have but I am getting exactly the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook quits (which can take some time) when its last visible window closes. To prevent that from happening, retrieve a `MAPIFolder` object (e.g. using `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolderFolder(olFolderInbox)`) and store the `Explorer` object returned by calling `MAPIFolder.GetExplorer()` in a global/class variable. The `Explorer` object does not have to be made visible.

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you :)